# Combining two different arrays in java

Tags: java

I really wanted to combine my two arrays and I really do not know what is wrong with my code it keeps giving me this results:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
    at javaDay3.ArrayExpanding.main(ArrayExpanding.java:17)
```

The results I want to view is :

```
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
```

Please help me to find what is wrong with my code:
I wanted to combine the two arrays manually using loops

```
package javaDay3;    
public class ArrayExpanding {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int ages [] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; // my first array
        for( int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {         
         int temp [] = new int [20];// my bigger and 2nd array
         for(int ix = 0; ix < temp.length; ix++) {          
          for(int ixx = 0; ixx <= temp.length; ixx++) {
            temp [0] = ages [0] ;               
            System.out.println(temp[ixx]);
          }
         }
        }
      }
}
```

should I add or remove something please help me I am using `Eclipse` and taking `Java`

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do here? Do you want to put all elements in `ages[]` to `temp[]`?

Comment: What do you want to do with this code? Combining two arrays or just reading one index by index? I don't really understand your code :D

Comment: yes i wanted to put all elements in ages [] to temp[]

Comment: Change `ixx <= temp.length` to `ixx < temp.length`. There it jumps out of bounds. No clue why that loop is even there, because you have 2 loops with the same condition.

Comment: @ignarapacon oki. Then you can follow my answer.

Comment: @ankur-singhal ignarapacon can't upvote since don't have enough reps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put all element in `ages[]` to `temp[]`, you can follow these steps.

1. let say you have two `arrays` as follows.

   ```
   int ages[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
   int temp[] = new int[20];
   ```

2.Then iterate the `ages` `array` and assign value of each element to `temp` `array`

```
    for(int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
        temp[i]=ages[i];
    }
```

3. Now your `temp` `array` contains what you want. You can print `temp` `array` either

```
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
    }
```

Or

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
```

Eg:

```
    int ages[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int temp[] = new int[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
        temp[i]=ages[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this method:

```
static int[] addElement(int[] a, int e) {
    a  = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
    a[a.length - 1] = e;
    return a;
}
```

You give it the List (a) and the element you want to add (e) and it returns the list with the added Element.

If you want to do it for multiple items you can just loop it, something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
    addElement(temp, ages[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int ages[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        for (int i = 0; i < ages.length; i++) {
            // System.out.println(ages[i]);
        }

        int temp[] = new int[20];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < temp.length; ix++) {

        }

        for (int ixx = 0; ixx < temp.length; ixx++) {
        if (ages.length > ixx) {
            temp[ixx] = ages[ixx];
        }
        System.out.println(temp[ixx]);
    }

    }
```

**output**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int ix = 0; ix < temp.length; ix++) 
  {
    if(ages.length>ix)//ages having lengh 10
        temp [ix] = ages [ix] ;
        else
        temp [ix] = 0 ;//if ages length exceeds
        System.out.println(temp[ix]);       
  }
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arraycopy method from System class.

```
int[] ages = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] temp = new int[20];
System.arraycopy(ages, 0, temp, 0, ages.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy from one array to another, loop through the array and assign it to the other.

```
 int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
 int temp[] = new int[a.length];

 for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     temp[i] = a[i];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "equals".

Change the line:

```
for (int ixx = 0; ixx <= temp.length; ixx++) {
```

with this:

```
for (int ixx = 0; ixx < temp.length; ixx++) {
```